# For Apache Geode, How should I do to turn off the Jetty version messages when occur 404 error

Tags: geode

We are using apache geode v1.6.0 and we also use Geode rest api.
However, when our customer do vulnerability test, they found a potential security risk and we need to fix that..

The report says, http://:7070 shows the following message

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Not Found
**Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.8.v20171121**
```

As you can see, Jetty version was shown, and this is reported as a risk.
I searched a lot and found we can turn off the message by configure Jetty setting as follows

```
<Item>
 <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
     <Set name="showContexts">false</Set>
 </New>
</Item>
```

But, Jetty is embedded in the Geode, how should I do to set the showContexts to false?

Any suggestion will be appreciate, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Embedded `Jetty Server` is started and configured in `Geode` through the [InternalHttpService](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-http-service/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/internal/cache/InternalHttpService.java) class, and this internal class doesn't provide any feature to manually configure the actual server properties or settings. The `showContexts` property within the `DefaultHandler` class, on the other hand, can't be configured through environment variables (which could be used as a workaround), it can only be configured through `xml` files (not used within `Geode`) or programatically.

Long story short: I don't think there's an out of the box way to disable the `DefaultHandler` as of now in `Geode`, I'd suggest to open a ticket through the [Geode JIRA System](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GEODE) and describe with details the actual issue and impact. The actual fix shouldn't be hard to implement on your own, though: just register a custom `ErrorHandler` or programatically set the `showContexts` property to `false` within the `DefaultHandler` instead, so you could submit a `PR` fixing the problem to get it merged into the `Geode`.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. I tried to fix this issue on my own, but failed to build the project. I will open a ticket on Geode JIRA, thanks for help.